# Oracle - Join two single column queries and perform a grouping

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table which I'm running two of the following queries on:

First query:

```
select distinct q1."InstituteId" from (
    select siid as "InstituteId" from ptable
      union all
    select riid as "InstituteId" from ptable
) q1
```

Second query:

```
select q2."InstituteId" from (
  select siid as "InstituteId" from ptable
    union all
  select riid as "InstituteId" from ptable
) q2
```

The objective is to get all the institutes from the first query (i.e)

```
InstituteId
1
1
2
3
3
4
...
```

And merge with distinct ids from the second query and perform a group by so the output looks like:

```
InstituteId    Count
1              2
2              1
3              2
...
```

I'm not sure how to proceed next. Please advise and thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what "merge with distinct ids from the second query" means.  Your sample data seems to indicate that you just want to `group by` the results of the first query.  Unless we're supposed to assume that you're not showing `InstituteId` 4 in your output because it doesn't exist in the results of the second query?

Comment: I do want to perform a simple group by - sorry if what I wrote may seem confusing. I just don't know how to go about it with a single column

Comment: So the second query is completely irrelevant to the question?  You just want to `group by` the results of the first query?

Comment: Yes - just realized when you asked the questions you did just now that I was overcomplicating it unnecessarily. I've posted an answer below... looks like it works. Thanks for making me question myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried this.. looks like I was overcomplicating things too much:

```
select q2."InstituteId", count(q2."InstituteId") as "COUNT" from (
  select siid as "InstituteId" from ptable
    union all
  select riid as "InstituteId" from ptable
  ) q2
  group by q2."InstituteId"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?:

```
SELECT InstituteId, COUNT(*)
FROM ptable
GROUP BY InstituteId
```